# Two WebSecurityConfigurerProviders for two-level authentication layer

Tags: java, spring-boot

Is it possible to set two custom `WebSecurityConfigurerProvider`s in order to authenticate most endpoints with one, and some requests with both?

I want all endpoints to have the correct api-key header, so I have this configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(1)
public class FirstLevelSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        AuthFilter authFilter = new AuthFilter(principalRequestHeader);
        authFilter.setAuthenticationManager(new AuthenticationManager() {

            @Override
            public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
                if (!someCondition()) {
                    throw new BadCredentialsException("The API key was not found or not the expected value.");
                }
                authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
                return authentication;
            }

        });

        httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .addFilter(authFilter).authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
        // cors
    }

}
```

But some certain endpoints should additionally have the second correct header present, so I wrote the second class with `@Order(2)` annotation hoping it would work:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(2)
public class SecondLevelSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        AuthFilter authFilter = new AuthFilter(principalRequestHeader);
        authFilter.setAuthenticationManager(new AuthenticationManager() {

            @Override
            public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
                if (!someOtherCondition()) {
                    throw new BadCredentialsException("The API key was not found or not the expected value.");
                }
                authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
                return authentication;
            }

        });

        httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .addFilter(authFilter).authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/certainEndpoint").authenticated();
    }

}
```

The problem is that the second config seems to be registered properly, but its `authentication` method is never called. Am I missing something here?